# Include another VBA project in PowerPoint

Tags: vba

I have a large project in VBA with lots of functionality that I would like to use in my program. When I run the program I get this

[image]

How can I make the prjGlobalPPT a part of VBAProject?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the project explicitly:

```
Application.Run prjGlobalPPT.ADV_UpdateChart
```

Comment: The same error appears but now for "prjGlobalPPT". It doesn't seem like my program can see the prjGlobalPPT evan though it is in the tree panel view

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to include prjGloabalPPT by filling in the properties under Tools.